# vim tabularize align selected rows

Tags: ruby, vim

How do you align selected rows with Vim Tabular plugin?
I have a code like:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  @name = attributes[:name]  
  @email = attributes[:email]
end
```

`:Tab /=` produces this, even with selecting rows `@name` and `@email` in visual mode.

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  @name                   = attributes[:name]  
  @email                  = attributes[:email]
end
```

How can one make vim tabularize plugin to format:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  @name  = attributes[:name]  
  @email = attributes[:email]
end
```

even with one row (the `@email` row) selected vim aligns the `=` in the rows `@name` and `@email` to that one in attributes `=`

Comment: The version I have (0.1) does what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're dead set on using [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [Tabularize](https://github.com/junegunn/tabularize) (I'm guessing you mean the first one), there's also [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) ([Github](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align)). They seem to do more or less the same, but Align works just fine for me on that piece of code.

- Align whole file: `:Align =`
- Align on visual line: `<leader>t=` or `:'<,'>Align =` (i.e. `:` from visual line).